# Exchange Web Services, funny problem with authentication, can't recieve mail from fixed email, but can from current user

Tags: windows, email, authentication, service, exchange-server

I'm using the fixed email address to get the files, becuase it's special email for agreements and etc...

But, I have found that, even I use the next code:

```
static string email = "rumosahrdata@rosinter.ru";

service.AutodiscoverUrl(email);
```

But, I don't get the mail from this email, I'm getting mails from my current user in Exchange ( and if another user try to do it, he will get mail from his own email, not from fixed ), seems to be because of Windows Authentication.

Why I have got such problem? And I wonder why method AutodiscoverUrl() - wants email without password?

Best Regards,

Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `.AutodiscoverUrl` you need to set [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.usedefaultcredentials%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) to `false` and assign [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.credentials%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) according to the account you want to access.

Otherwise the current user (Windows authentication/current Outlook-Profile) is the default...